# Catching undeclared use of a filehandle in Perl

Tags: perl, handle

The following Perl program does not output any error during execution. Is there a way to raise an exception while execution for trying to print to an undeclared handle? For the case below, the undeclared handle will be `STD_ERR` and `DOES_NOT_EXIST`.

```
use strict;

print STD_ERR        "(UNDECLARED) DOES NOT PRINT\n";
print STDERR         "     (EXIST) DOES PRINT\n";
print DOES_NOT_EXIST "(UNDECLARED) DOES NOT PRINT\n";
```

Although the above code is simplified to illustrate the problem,
I kind of wasted couple of tens of minutes trying to figure out the issue in my real program. In my real program, I realized that I misspelled the handle I want to print against. I want to avoid this kind of waste of time, but `use strict;` simply doesn't do it.

Comment: You should always add `use warnings` to your scripts (in addition to the `use strict` you already have). Additionally, you should use lexical filehandles rather than global ones. _ie_, do `open my fh, '>', ...` rather than `open FH, '>', ...`. (of course, this doesn't apply to `STDERR`...)

Comment: With lexical filehandles `strict` does help. That indeed doesn't work for `STDeRR` but with consistent use of lexicals for all handles the `STDERR` stream would be the _only_  such case.  (Hakon's answer not only solves that but is a good idea in general, along with `use strict;`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `use warnings 'unopened'` to warn about usage of unopened file handles. To make the warning fatal (i.e. throw an exception) you can use:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';
```

See also [perldoc warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) and [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)